# Return Quickest Result

Tags: aws-step-functions

Let's say I have two methods for completing a task, `MethodA` & `MethodB` to do `Task1`. How can I have a Step Function which executes both methods, and completes `Task1` as soon as `A` or `B` has finished, and then proceeds to `Task2`.